# Missing Chapterwise working examples for Manipulation after local installation

Tags: drake, drake-r-package

I plan to extend and use the Drake simulator working examples on manipulation as a part of learning phase in projects from manipulation.mit.edu.

I followed the instructions as per the link below:-
https://manipulation.mit.edu/drake.html#section3

python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip3 install manipulation --extra-index-url https://drake-packages.csail.mit.edu/whl/nightly/

But the last line above failed and I replaced it with
pip3 install manipulation --extra-index-url https://drake-packages.csail.mit.edu/whl/nightly/ 'drake<0.1'

Please see the attached picture where after searching for the notebook files (with extensions .ipynb), I do not see the chapterwise examples. Can you please help in resolving the issue?

Regards
Sandeep.

Tried the installation steps as per the instructions provided, but did not work.

Answer (score 0):

The `manipulation` pip package contains the supporting library, but not the actual example notebooks for each chapter of the book. You can get those example notebooks by cloning the repository directly: `http://github.com/RussTedrake/manipulation`.

I will try to make those instructions more clear.

Comment: Thanks Russ Tedrake for the clarification.